# Handle java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

Tags: java

I'm using this code to read value from a file.

```
public String getChassisSerialNumber() throws IOException
{
    File myFile = new File("/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_serial");
    byte[] fileBytes;
    String content = "";
    if (myFile.exists()) 
    {          
        fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(myFile.toPath());

        if (fileBytes.length > 0) 
        {
            content = new String(fileBytes);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return "No file";
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        return "No file";
    }
    return null;
}
```

I get this error:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_serial
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3149)
```

How I can handle this error? Because now I the code stops execution? Is there some better way without interruption the code execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use try-catch, either within `getChassisSerialNumber()` on when calling it. E.g.

```
try {
    getChassisSerialNumber();
} catch (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException e) {
    System.out.println("caught exception");
}
```

OR

```
try {
    fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(myFile.toPath());
} catch (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException e) {
    return "access denied";
}
```

This way your program does not terminate.

For a clean design you should either `return null` in cases you could not read the file (returning "magic strings like "No file" or "access denied" are no good design, because you cannot differentiate if this string came from the file or not) *or* catch the exception outside of the method (my first example).

Btw. by just putting the content of the file into the `content` variable you don't return it (i.e., replace `content = new String(fileBytes);` with `return new String(fileBytes);`)

```
public String getChassisSerialNumber()
{
    File myFile = new File("/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_serial");
    if (myFile.exists()) 
    {          
        byte[] fileBytes;
        try {
            fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(myFile.toPath());
        } catch (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException e) {
            return null;
        }

        if (fileBytes != null && fileBytes.length > 0) 
        {
            return new String(fileBytes);
        } 
    } 
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer. Is there something else that I can improve into the code.

Comment: Btw. you should not update the question to include the answer, because this way nobody will ever understand the answers lateron.

Comment: Could you paste the complete example?

Comment: I already did that. YOu could also make it even shorter, but this way it stil follows your logic.

Answer (score 1):

You should catch the exception instead of throwing it. I think that you need to put a try-catch block around the call to the method *getChassisSerialNumber*.

Something like this should work in your case:

```
String result = null;

try {
     result = getChassisSerialNumber();         
} catch (java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException ex) {
      // do something with the exception
      // you can log it or print some specific information for the user
}

return result; // if the result is null, the method has failed
```

In order to understand better this kind of things you should have a look to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html)