# java.nio.file.Paths - How to skip unaccessible file/folder while iterating

Tags: java, directory, iteration

I am writing code to iterate through all folders that i can access.
However my program stops when on folder is inaccessible.

How do i bypass that folder and keep looking for others?
Or, in other words, how do i show folders and files i have access to?

i am using java.nio.file.Paths (Java 8).

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitOption;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

// Test File D:\TEST\test.jpg
public class TestIteration{

    // Main
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Iterate through folders
        String rootFolder = "c:\\";    
        WalkDirTree(rootFolder); // Walks through directory tree and print names of directories/files.      
    }


    // Prints all file/directory names in the entire directory tree
    private static void WalkDirTree(String rootFolder) throws Exception {                   
        Files.walk(Paths.get(rootFolder)).forEach(path -> {
            System.out.println(path);
        });

        System.out.println("_______________________________________DONE");
    }

}
```

Comment: If by "stops" you mean "throws an exception" just catch the exception and deal with it.

Comment: and method names should start with a lowercase in Java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handle java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350157/handle-java-nio-file-accessdeniedexception)

Comment: what do you mean 'inaccessible' ? Are you talking about a specific exception?

Comment: I know lambdas are fun, but in this case, you might be better off with [Files.walkFileTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-), which lets you deal with each file’s status individually.

Answer (score 1):

If by *inaccessible* you're referring to "not readable", then I reckon you can use [`Files#isReadable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isReadable-java.nio.file.Path-); from its documentation:

> Tests whether a file is readable. This method checks that a file exists and that this Java virtual machine has appropriate privileges that would allow it open the file for reading. Depending on the implementation, this method may require to read file permissions, access control lists, or other file attributes in order to check the effective access to the file. Consequently, this method may not be atomic with respect to other file system operations.

Your code would look like:

```
Files.walk(Paths.get(rootFolder)).filter(Files::isReadable).forEach(path -> {
    System.out.println(path);
});
```

Comment: I love the idea but its not working. It stil stops at java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18

Comment: I was trying to apply a try and catch to the lambda expression for each path and file but can't find a way to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.  I'll see if I can recreate your issue, but it's possible that you might have to use something other than a stream here to solve it.

Answer (score -2):

While streams are certainly beautiful, you might need to deal with each inaccessible file individually.

In that case, you could choose to have a simple `for` loop by using the [FileUtils.listFiles](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean)) method from `org.apache.commons.io`

```
String[] extensions = {"png","txt"}; // file extensions you might want to target
Collection fileObjects= FileUtils.listFiles(new File("dirPath"),extensions,true);
for (Object obj : fileObjects){
     File file = (File) obj;
     if (!Files.isReadable(file.toPath())) continue; // or do smth else
}
```

If you wish to target all files regardless their extensions, then pass `null` instead of the a `String` array.

If you do not wish recursive search, then pass `false` instead of `true`